# Create a subdomain under a domain and use that domain for email ticketing service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

A platform for email ticketing service. So the basic workflow is like,

When user signup (representing the tenant), we need to create a subdomain under our main domain. After that, we need to verify it to use with SES with any username on that domain.

For example, 
We have a domain  =  domain.com 
we need to create  a subdomain for tenant = tenant1.subdomain.com 
Then we need to create a mail id for that subdomain = support@tenant1.subdomain.com

How to achieve as the example given above? How to create a subdomain and create an SES mail for that subdomain and verify it? I know we need to use Route53. But our domain is not registered through AWS Route53. It is done through a third-party DNS provider.

So how to do this entire step through APIs? Can you explain with basic details like what to do with domain and how to achieve the SES mail verification process too for the subdomain?
Domain Name or Record Set:

Comment: You don't need a subdomain delegation set for subdomain, you just need to verify tenant1.subdomain.com in your SES and create a simple TXT record for this and domain can be used for sending emails, when user register, you can run some php mailer or something and use your subdomain to send emails to them. This can be done in your existing DNS provider also as you're just publishing a simple txt record for tenant1.subdomain.com.

Comment: I am using route53 and SES. So how could I do that?

Comment: You just need to add first a subdomain in SES e.g: subdomain.example.com and create a record _amazonses.subdomain.example.com and create a TXT record or you can just simply create a TXT record for subdomain.example.com unless this domain is used for CNAME record.